# Why does not NDSolve[..] work!

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

I have this model with 4 ODEs and it tells me that I should give an initial value for `m1[t]` but I give it as is clear from the `Code` below. Can you show me where the mistakes are?

```
NDSolve[
{
  Derivative[1][SS][t]==-0.0322-(0.016 II[t])/SS[t]-0.1 SS[t]-(0.016 SS[t])/II[t],
  Derivative[1][II][t]==0.0322+II[t] (-0.066+0.016/SS[t])+(0.016 SS[t])/II[t],
  Derivative[1][m1][t]==-0.709 + 0.129/II[t] - (0.129 II[t])/SS[t]^2,
  Derivative[1][m2][t]==-0.697 + 0.129/SS[t] - (0.129 SS[t])/II[t]^2,
  SS[0]==0.99, II[0]==0.001, SS[T]==0.001, II[T]==0.00001, m1[0]==2, m2[0] == 3.1
}, {SS[t], II[t], m1[t], m2[t]}, {t, 0, 50}
       ]
```

Comment: You have 4 first order equations which require 4 conditions and you have 6.  Also I don't see `T` assigned a value anywhere.  As far as `m1`, I think the other errors are confusing Mathematica.  Assign a value for `T` and you get a too many conditions error rather than the `m1` error.

Comment: @Bill Watts: T is not a problem, it was simply forgotten when copy-past. I gave boundary conditions because the MMA was asking for it. Worst of all, I did all these in a newly created NB and still MMA is asking for m1 initial value. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: When I cut out the two conditions involving `T`, I get answers, although the solution blows up about `t = 7`.  MMA does not ask me for more conditions or for the starting value of `m1`.

Comment: @Bill Watts: Exactly. I tried the same thing and found out that the system runs until 7.009. I thought that maybe there is a way to systematically jump over the points of `explosions` by increasing the step size. The example system is much easier than what I actually have and such discontinuities often arise simply because of small step size for the convergence algorithm used in MMA.

Comment: `SS[t]` is in the denominator of all your equations and it goes to zero at around `t = 7`.  I think the blow up is not something you can just jump over.

Comment: @Bill Watts: You are right. Surprisingly, although Lagrange multipliers and `SS[t], II[t]` all appear in the denominator of the actual equations, `NDSolve[...]` gives me an output without any error nor warning after giving initial conditions for all (6) right-hand side variables in the model. The output is hard to digest but at least the `Code` runs well without any trouble. I will put the running model as edit and you might want to try it yourself. Thank you so much for your time and thoughts.